# All Post Requests have 302 Found Error in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a Wordpress site to maintain. I use Apache for server. I don't know for what reason that all post requests have 302 Found response, which leads to url redirect. This makes my site unable to post anything, make any update.

For example:

1. I visit login.php
2. post username and password
3. I receive 302 Found error, with Location: index.php
4. my browser then GET index.php

Can you suggest to me what I should look at? I have tried:

1. .htaccess RewriteEngine Off

But the problem is still there. All GET requests have no problem. But only POST requests have problem.

My htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
CheckSpelling on
</IfModule>
RewriteRule ^search/?$  search.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^about-us/?$  about-us.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^country/?$  country.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^city/?$  city.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^city/letter/(.*)/$  city.php?city=$1 [NC,L]
```

It seems that Wordpress is prone to these 302 Redirect problem.

More info:
Most of the php files that handle POST also handle GET. For instance, login.php is itself a login form and also has coded to handle login processing.

Thank you very much for any response.

Comment: Are you using Apache or NGINX? If it's Apache, please post the contents of your htaccess. Have you checked if there are any rewrites in the virtual host? (My guess is that the redirect is dependent of trailing slash).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks for response. It is Apache. But I have tried Redirect Off. But the problem is still there.

Comment: What do you mean by `Redirect Off`? Where did you put that? Is that really the complete htaccess? If it is, you're not using nice urls with Wordpress?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sorry. Should be RewriteEngine Off. It is complete htaccess. Thank you

Comment: @MagnusEriksson So what do you think is the cause for such strange problem? POST has 302 error but not GET?

Comment: I'm still waiting for an answer to the question: _"Have you checked if there are any rewrites in the virtual host?"_

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Hi, should be no. because in apache2.conf I can't see any <VirtualHost> tag.